# How can I prevent double data from being shown in my loop PHP

Tags: php, sql, loops

I have a script to show related products of a product. These are shown in a shopping cart, this shopping cart can have multiple products so if for example product 1 and product 2 have the same related products, all of them are shown twice.

I only need them to be shown once, how can I do that?

My current script:

```
$relatedarticles = '
SELECT
  cnt.catid,
  cnt.title AS content_title,
  cnt.alias AS content_alias,
  cnt.introtext,
  cnt.images,
  cnt.state,
  f.field_id,
  f.item_id,
  f.value,
  cat.title AS cat_title,
  cat.id
FROM snm_content cnt
  LEFT JOIN snm_fields_values f
  ON cnt.id = f.item_id
  LEFT JOIN snm_categories cat
  ON cnt.catid = cat.id
WHERE cnt.alias = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($cartproduct1['alias']).'"
AND field_id = 10
AND cnt.state = 1';
$relatedarticlescon = $conn->query($relatedarticles);
while($relatedarticles = $relatedarticlescon->fetch_assoc()){

  $relhtml .= '<div class="relatedwrapper">';
  $rel = '
  SELECT
   cnt.title AS content_title,
   cnt.alias AS content_alias,
   cnt.introtext,
   cnt.images,
   cnt.state,
   cat.title AS cat_title,
   cat.alias AS cat_alias
  FROM snm_content cnt
    LEFT JOIN snm_categories cat
    ON cnt.catid = cat.id
  WHERE cnt.id = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($relatedarticles['value']).'"
  AND cnt.state = 1';
  $relcon = $conn->query($rel);

  while($rel = $relcon->fetch_assoc()){

    $relimage = $rel['images'];
    $relimg = json_decode($relimage);

    if ($relimg->image_intro != "") {
      $imgrel = 'cms/'.$relimg->image_intro;
    }else{
      $imgrel = 'images/_bad_noimg.jpg';
    }

    $relhtml .= '
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="relateda" href="'.$rel['cat_alias'].'-huren/'.$rel['content_alias'].'">
        <div class="relatedcontent">
          <span class="titlespan">'.$rel['content_title'].'</span>
          <span class="catspan">'.$rel['cat_title'].'</span>
          <img src="'.$imgrel.'">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>';
  }
}
```

`$relatedarticles['value']` contains all related product ids.

Comment: You should describe your database data model better.

Comment: @RadimBača Why you need my database model? I only need `$relatedarticles['value']` to not have any double occurences in my loop.

Answer (score 0):

A simple list might do the job just well:

```
$shownRelated = array();
while($rel = $relcon->fetch_assoc()){
   if (isset($shownRelated[$relatedarticles['value']])) {
      continue;
   }
   $shownRelated[$relatedarticles['value']] = true;

...

}
```

This simply creates a list of products shown to the customer and will prevent it from being displayed a second (or nth) time.